# Azure table storage - using next_row_key returns the same chunk

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to use the continuation token from a query_entities response to retrieve the next 1000 values but it I get the same 1000 back.

My code

```
rows = table_service.query_entities(
    'tableName', "PartitionKey eq '6'", top=1000)

nextRowKey = rows.x_ms_continuation['NextRowKey']

rows = table_service.query_entities(
    'tableName', "PartitionKey eq '6'",
    next_row_key=nextRowKey, top=1000)
```

Am I doing something wrong? From the explanation in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py) it seems like it should be working.

Comment: When you receive continuation token, you will receive both `NextPartitionKey` and `NextRowKey`. Please try to use both of them when you fetch the next set of entities. That should work!

Comment: You are right, I couldn't have guessed though! If you compile an answer I will mark the question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When table service returns a continuation token, you get two things back - `NextPartitionKey` and `NextRowKey`. To fetch the next set of entities, you would need to use both of them. Please do something like the following:

```
rows = table_service.query_entities(
    'tableName', "PartitionKey eq '6'", top=1000)

nextRowKey = rows.x_ms_continuation['NextRowKey']
nextPartitionKey = rows.x_ms_continuation['NextPartitionKey']

rows = table_service.query_entities(
    'tableName', "PartitionKey eq '6'", next_partition_key=nextPartitionKey,
    next_row_key=nextRowKey, top=1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a pattern that works for me (uses 0.33.0 of azure storage), only improvement I would like to see is how better to combine the result sets.

```
def GetData(tableService, tableName, dataFilter):   
    #https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py
    keyMarkers = {}
    keyMarkers['nextpartitionkey'] = 0
    keyMarkers['nextrowkey'] = 0 
    b=[]
    while True:
        #get a batch of data
        a = tableService.query_entities(table_name=tableName, filter=dataFilter,num_results=1000 ,marker=keyMarkers)
        #copy results to list
        for item in a.items:
            b.append(item)
        #check to see if more data is available
        if len(a.next_marker) == 0:
            del a
            break
        #if more data available setup current position
        keyMarkers['nextpartitionkey'] = a.next_marker['nextpartitionkey']
        keyMarkers['nextrowkey'] = a.next_marker['nextrowkey'] 
        #house keep temp storage
        del a
    #return final list
    return b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the newest version of `azure-storage-table` (that is hidden in `azure-cosmosdb-table` pip package) you get iteration over 1000-long chunks for free. `top` param for `query_entities` is even no longer available.

This snippet works for me with `azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.5`:

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService

service = TableService(connection_string='xxxxx')
table_name = 'yyyy'

rows = service.query_entities(table_name, "PartitionKey lt '2014-07-01'")
for row in rows:
    # do sth with row
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround that solves that problem. Since I cannot use the continuation token for grabbing the next row key, I am updating the query using the last row key manually and I use the continuation token only as termination condition.

Here is an example of a range query. Let's say that we want to retrieve all the values between row keys `123456789` and `123457689`, which span in a range larger than 1000 rows.

```
rows = table_service.query_entities(
    'tableName', ("PartitionKey eq '6' Rowkey gt '123456789' and "
                  "Rowkey lt '123457689'"), top=1000)

data = rows

while hasattr(rows, 'x_ms_continuation'):
    # now using the last retrieved rowkey inside the query
    rows = table_service.query_entities(
        'tableName', ("PartitionKey eq '6' Rowkey gt '" + 
                      rows[len(rows)-1].RowKey + "' and "
                      "Rowkey lt '123457689'"), top=1000)
    data.extend(rows)
```

Comment: See Gaurav's comment. You're simply not sending both components of the continuation token.

Comment: You do realize though that there is a lack of documentation here, right? I don't think it is reasonable to expect that someone would have just guessed that.

Comment: If you check out the [docs for query_entites](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py#L399) they say how to get them from the result of the last listing operation and how to pass them. That being said, we are adding more convenient continuation token handling in the next version.

Comment: Of course I checked that before posting here. I still don't see where it is stated that both parameters should be included. Both parameters are referred to as optional and the only requirement to both is supposed to be top.